# Fed 15 Gysahl Greens to a single Chobobo - It is still not tamed. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-hexxit

According to the Hexxit wiki it takes 2 to 4 Gysahl Greens to tame a Chocobo,  yet I have used 15 so far on one chocobo and it is still not tamed.   What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You probably just need to feed it more. You seem to just be having bad luck. Sorry :(

Comment: I acquired about 90 greens,  went over to one of the chocobos, and spammed it,  after giving it about 20 of them the hearts finally appeared.

Answer (score -1):

If you used the wrong one, then use the one that is found on the ground. It can take from 1 to infinty for it to work.